# What are "dummy terminals"

Tags: power, analog, relay, power-electronics, electromagnetism

This picture is in datasheet of one relay:

[image]

From this picture I assume that if there's current flow between 1 and 8 pins, the relay will connect 3 and 4, right?
 What are "dummy terminals"? 
Does it mean that 5 and 6 pins are unused in this model? So whatever happens with 1 and 8 pins, nothing will change with 5 and 6?

Comment: Yes. 5 and 6 are not connected.

Answer (score 2):

5, 6 are poorly worded (for western English) **N**o **C**onnect (N.C.) terminals.
This is a generic physical part, that sometimes is configured as a DPST relay, but what you are showing is a SPST relay.

Comment: Isn't it NC - normally closed vs. NO - normally open? Not "no connect"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Good point!  That's the problem with acronyms. In schematics NC usually means no connect.  On relays, it means normally closed.  So what does it mean on the schematic of a relay?  Maybe that's why they chose "dummy terminal"?

Comment: "Not used" is also used in this context.